# Looping a function for multiple lookups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that search for a part number in a different sheet, and imports all of the times the part had failed inspection. The problem is that I have multiple cases when a part failed, so they fall into different rows. Right now I am able to call up one instance using the following formula;

```
=INDEX('QN Data'!$A3:$A10000,MATCH($B$4,'QN Data'!$D$3:$D$10000,0))
```

There are a total of 6 different occurrences that I need transferred. Now is there a way for excel to remember where it left off on and start from there?

Also I cannot use any macros. We currently have one that does all of this, but my boss does not like using them. I tried filling the formula down but it just gives me the QN number that is below the one for the part number I want which is a different part number completely.

Comment: pivot table? or if you just need to count the fails, what about `countif`?

Comment: Because the *MATCH()* gives the first row found, begin the next search at one row below the first find rather than $D$3.

Comment: I need the exact information. Like the reason it failed, how we are going to prevent it from happening again, and the QN number which pertains to the form the inspector had to fill out.

Comment: I tried doing that but it gives me the incorrect QN number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a multiple match using the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to force anything that does not match into an error and ignore the errors.

```
=INDEX('QN Data'!$A$3:$A$10000, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$9998)/('QN Data'!$D$3:$D$10000=$B$4), ROW(1:1)))
```

You are actually using the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function of the AGGREGATE function so you can get the second, third, etc. successive matches by increasing the *k* paramter. I done this above by using `ROW(1:1)` which equals 1 but will increase to 2, 3, etc as the formula is filled down.

The relative row position *within* 'QN Data'!$A$3:$A$10000 is returned by forcing any row position that does not match into a `#DIV/0!` error state. The **6** option tells AGGREGATE to ignore errors.

You may wish to put an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) around the formula so that you can fill down for more rows than necessary without showing `#NUM!` errors when you run out of matches.